# My guitar pupil is a pregnant woman. Should she keep playing classical guitar?

Tags: classical-guitar, classical-music

What are the consequences for the baby ? Are there any studies that would have noticed positive / negative consequences on the baby of the vibrations a classical guitar induces on the belly and the chest ?

Should the avoid playing dissonant chords ? Playing loud ? Playing notes that would be near the resonance frequency of her belly ? (frequency that should get lower and lower as the belly gets larger)

Comment: My Guitar Wants To Kill Your Mama!   OK, seriously, there is absolutely no risk from the incredibly low energy output of a guitar. Compare with, e.g., the output of the ultrasound monitor used prenatally.  Meanwhile, lots of people swear that playing music calms (or even educates!) the fetus.

Comment: Surely she should *only* play dissonant chords? Got to avoid too much resonance! :)

Comment: @carlwitthoft : the pregnant woman is the guitarist :)

Comment: Skippy,  I sure hope you get the reference!  :=)

Comment: No I don't sorry...

Comment: Check out Weasels Ripped My Flesh.

Comment: I was assuming this question had more to do with technique and a big baby belly getting in the way!  Very interesting to consider dissonance and resonant frequencies in the womb though.  Also, Frank Zappa ftw!

Answer (score 11):

This is a positive thing. Studies have shown the positive effect music has on unborn babies, see: 
Whitwell, Giselle E. "The importance of prenatal sound and music." Journal of Prenatal and Perinatal Psychology and Health 13 (1999): 255-262.

http://intraspec.ca/music.pdf

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a catastrophic fall from 20 feet in height, A mother's body will protect the unborn child from harm.  The mother might not survive, but the baby likely will.  Given that, I find it impossible to imagine how playing classical guitar could harm the baby.

When my wife was pregnant, she used to sit on my bass amplifier as I was playing, which would make the baby rouse and kick. That baby went on to become an extremely intelligent adult with absolutely no rhythm.  :)

The only possible downside to playing classical guitar while very pregnant is posture difficulties for mom.